# Generating pdf file using symfony framework

Tags: symfony1, pdf-generation, symfony-1.4

I'm using Symfony 1.4 and I have to create pdf file from Word/HTML with some fields added by user using form.
I've met this problem in plain php few years ago, but I wonder if there is any ready solution in Symfony framework? Or someone wants to share his idea about this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been using http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfTCPDFPlugin with Symfony 1.4 and haven't run into any problems yet. The sfTCPDFPlugin provides abstraction for the TCPDF, an open source PHP class for generating PDF documents.

Comment: Thanks for help.I would like only to add that for symfony 1.4  mentioned plugin must be installed by copying the contents to directory manually - not by the cli, because for this version of symfony plugin is depreciated. Thanks once again. :)